# React Component not updating after calling setState in SocketIO event listener

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, socket.io

I have a class component. I've added this line in the constructor:

```
this.handleChangedCells = this.handleChangedCells.bind(this);
```

I register a SocketIO listener in componentDidMount and call a function like so

```
socket.on("changedCells", this.handleChangedCells);
```

I am receiving the data as I console.log it once I receive it. The problem is that the function calls this.setState and it does not update the component. I have

```
handleChangedCells(data) {
    console.log(data);
    let new_board = this.state.board;
    data.map(arr => {
      arr.map(obj => {
        new_board[obj.ind[0]][obj.ind[1]] = {
          color: obj.color,
          alive: obj.alive
        };
      });
    });

    this.setState({ board: new_board });
}
```

The component that I have is as follows:

```
render() {
    return (
      <div className="boardContainer" style={container_style}>
        {this.state.board.map((row, r_ind) => {
          return (
            <div className="row" key={r_ind}>
              {row.map((col, c_ind) => {
                return (
                  <Cell
                    key={[r_ind, c_ind]}
                    cell_row_index={c_ind}
                    cell_col_index={r_ind}
                    socketProps={socket}
                    colorProps={this.state.color}
                    clickedColorProps={col.color}
                    aliveProps={col.alive}
                  />
                );
              })}
            </div>
          );
        })}
      </div>
    );
  }
```

As you can see, the component depends on the state which I update however, the component is not updated... Any idea of what is happening here?

**EDIT**: Here's a link to my project https://github.com/Dobermensch/ExpressTest.git The file in question is /client/components/Game.js

**Edit 2**: board is an array of arrays containing objects {color: [x,y,z], alive: boolean} and I am getting the changed cells, (dead cells) and marking them as dead in the board so ideally I would go the the dead cell's index and mark it as dead by board[row][col] = {color: [x,y,z], alive: false}

**Edit 3**: data structure of board is [[{}.{},{}],[{},{},{}]] and I am changing the properties of objects within the array

Comment: do not mutate the state.

Comment: Do you get some error?

Comment: am I mutating the state? and I get no errors

Comment: You are mutating state: `let new_board = this.state.board;` Now `new_board === this.state.board` so `this.setState({ board: new_board });` would be the same as `this.setState({ board: this.sate.board });` and would cause React to not detect any changes. We don't know what `this.state.board` is so can't really give you an answer as to how to set it.

Comment: In that case, since board is an array of arrays, how would I change one element in it and set the new "board" as state? I've tried `let new_board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(this.state.board));` and then making the changes in new_board then setting new_board as state but still no luck

Comment: @Ayudh, If `JSON` encoding and decoding didn't work means. You can use the `map` to generated the deep clone. Refer my answer.

Comment: Please have a look at my third edit and see if it helps

Answer (score 1):

I had faced similar issue while I had the combination of nested `objects` and `array`. I think `setState` doesn't handle nested updates very well.

Another problem is in your code. You are actually mutating the `state`.

`let new_board = this.state.board;` Here the board is an `array`. Javascript does not deep clone `array` and `object`. You are assigning the `refererence` of the `board` `array` to the new variable.

So, what you can do is just `deep clone` the board `array`.

```
let new_board = this.state.board.map(item => {...item}); // You may need to handle the multiple levels.
```

Also `JSON.stringy` and `JSON.parse` should work.

```
let new_board = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(array));
```

Once, you have the `deep clone` of the `state`. You can modify the data and `setState` should trigger the rerender.

**Update 1:**

As you are using the state of the Cell to update it. The prop values are not updated on re-render.

So you should use [getDerivedStateFromProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#static-getderivedstatefromprops) in your `Cell` component to make the `prop` data available to `state`.

```
static getDerivedStateFromProps(props, state) {
    return {
      r: props.clickedColorProps[0],
      g: props.clickedColorProps[1],
      b: props.clickedColorProps[2],
      alive: props.aliveProps
    };
  }
```

**Note** that the `getDerivedStateFromProps` will execute on every rerender of the component, even when the state change. So, you should have a condition inside the method to return the proper data.

Comment: I basically made two for loops and used `Object.assign()` to clone the objects and created a new board then changed the objects within and assigned it to state but still no cigar...

Comment: @Ayudh, Can you create a codepen which reproduce the issue?

Comment: @Ayudh Check [this one](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-setstate-not-updating-npm9n) out

Comment: Added sandbox code demo https://codesandbox.io/embed/sample-react-webpack-hdsug

Comment: I can see the `state` getting updated. Added `console.log('rerender', this.state.board);` in render. The `handleChangedCells` is updating the correct index of the `board`

Comment: @James state is updating just fine (even better when my code was used as it doesn't needlessly copy state that **doesn't** change) but the props that Game.js passes to Cell.js is only set in Cell.js constructor so it's further ignored when Game.js re renders. I asked Ayudh why Cell.js has local state instead of just using the props passed from Game.js

Comment: It is because the `Cell` state is not updated on rerender. Check the update to the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Please don't do a deep copy with JSON.parse, it is a really bad idea because you're creating new objects for **everything** and not only the things that change. If you know what pure components are then you know why JSON.parse is bad.

You can change only the things that need to change with the following code:

```
handleChangedCells(data) {
  console.log(data);
  let new_board = [...this.state.board];
  data.forEach(arr => {
    arr.forEach(obj => {
      //shallow copy only if it's not copied already
      if (
        new_board[obj.ind[0]] ===
        this.state.board[obj.ind[0]]
      ) {
        new_board[obj.ind[0]] = [
          ...new_board[obj.ind[0]],
        ];
      }
      new_board[obj.ind[0]][obj.ind[1]] = {
        color: obj.color,
        alive: obj.alive,
      };
    });
  });
  this.setState({ board: new_board });
}
```

If it still "doesn't work" then I suggest creating a [sandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/sample-react-webpack-2s2ny) demonstrating the problem. Instead of a real xhr you can just return changed sample data.

Demo of it working is [here](https://codesandbox.io/s/so-setstate-not-updating-npm9n)

Comment: sandbox : https://codesandbox.io/embed/sample-react-webpack-hdsug

Comment: @Ayudh You are passing clickedColorProps prop from Game.js to Cell.js and then you don't really do anything with it except in constructor. Why not just use that prop in render? The problem is that the Cell.js constructor is not re run when you render again so what Game.js passes to Cell.js is ignored even though your setState worked. You also did not use the code in my answer for your example.

Comment: I see, thanks for the explanation. Could you explain what you mean by `Why not just use that prop in render?` My rationale here is that, in fact, the server gives color to the cells which is the average of it's neighbours, therefore, I couldn't think of a way to give the cell a default color on click but also allow for its color to change to what the server demands. I decided to pass in the default color to the constructor so that onClick a cell is assigned its default color and the new updated color is passed as Props to the Cell by Game. I'm implementing a colored Conway's game of life.

Comment: @Ayudh So when you first render the Cell you'd like it to use the clickedColorProps and when you clicked the cell you'd like to use colorProps? The names suggest the reverse but that could be a naming problem.